# Use same text multiple times in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have few functions, that should be described in doxygen where 80% of description is the same.
I can copy-paste it over them, but sometimes this description is changing, and supporting changes in all those functions is becoming headache.

Is there a way in doxygen to create a named text block, that will be typed just once, and each function will be able to use it?

Something like that:

```
//! /textblock <supername> that is the text that I would like to have just once, but that should appears in different places in documentation
...
//! my function 1. /useblock <supername>. Just as it is.
void func1() { return; }
...
//! my function 2. /useblock <supername>. Yeah, make sense.
void func2() { return; }
...
//! my function 3. /useblock <supername>. Such great it is.
void func3() { return; }
```

Comment: I think the \snippetdoc is the command you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the "alias" custom command in doxygen for implementing "snippets". See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html. Although the explanation makes it look like you can use this only for function-type things, it's great for repeated text.